# focus on input Google search

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-search

I would like to develop a firefox extension that allows me to focus on the google search. https://www.google.fr

I tired to make `document.getElementById("lst-ib").focus();`, 
If I analyze the DOM with `DOM inspector` the input field have the id `lst-ib`, but the focus does not switch but if I made a `document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "test";`  the word `test` appears good in the input field. I feel that all the javascript functions work except the `focus()`.

Is it therefore possible to focus on this field or google blocks this action maybe ?

**EDIT**

Js Google function event on focus :

```
function(a, f) {
  if (d.length) {
     var g;
     if (!(g = a)) {
         g = {};
         var k = c.event;
         k && (k.keyCode && (g.keyCode = k.keyCode), g.i1 = !0)
     }
     g.dg = f || b;
     for (var k = g, l, m, n = 0, ba; ba = d[n++];) ba.sD ? m = !0 : l 
          || (ba.j1 ? QS_pWa(this, ba, k) : l = ba.Cg(k));
     if (m)
       for (n = 0; ba = d[n];) ba.sD ? d.splice(n, 1) : ++n;
     if (g.Uh) return delete g.Uh, g.i1 && (g = c.event || g), QS_Et(g), g.returnValue = !1
   }
}
```

But this is incomprehensible...

Comment: Maybe they perform .focus() for some other element such as a button? Search "focus" on their js to find out

Comment: Yes I have try to do this, but their `JS` is obfuscated so unreadable @Francisco Presencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `focus()` is right and google isn't blocking that method, but because the focus is on Inspector, it does not seems focus on search input element. Type this and click google page's margin:

`setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("lst-ib").focus(), 2000)`

Comment: it does not work, after research Google has a `focus` event on the input field, the problem is that the function is obfuscated and incomprehensible @youngminz

Comment: Ah yes it's work, it did not work because I do not click on the page, after I run my script... Thank's